# Difference between “Generally, I am…” and “I am generally…”?

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage

Revisiting my CV, I have stumbled over a small question.

I originally wrote:

> *“I am generally willing and able to relocate worldwide.”*

Today, I noticed I could also write:

> *“Generally, I am willing and able to relocate worldwide.”*

Now, I'm a bit confused which one to use. Maybe this origins from the fact that English is not my native language…

Is there any – no matter how subtle – difference in meaning when putting the word “generally” in front of that sentence?

As that line is part of my CV, I guess most important for me is to understand if there is any reason why I should prefer one version over the other. Or doesn't it matter which one I use?

Comment: I don't think there's any possibility of a difference in meaning here. But the word ***generally*** does strike me as slightly "odd". Usually in such contexts it's synonymous with ***usually/normally***, but unless OP has accepted positions that entailed "worldwide relocation" several times in the past (and *turned down* at least one such position) it doesn't make a lot of sense. I would discard the word completely, and deal with that "less likely possibility" if and when it arises.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To explain the context a bit: that is somewhat of a closing line which is meant to indicate that *I am surely willing and able to move worldwide for a job… if relocating for the job actually makes sense*. I have relocated for work several times in the past, but I also had to turn down offers frequently because they simply didn't provide the details needed to make relocation worthwhile (for example: salary too low, temporary contract, and alike things).

Comment: “For the right position, I am willing and able to relocate worldwide, and have done so before.”

Comment: (Following on E.A.'s comment) Why not simply: *“I am willing to relocate worldwide, and have done so before.”* All the other stuff is understood, such as adequate compensation to move, etc. That keeps it short, and also indicates that you've moved before, and so, your documentation is up to date (such as passport). You should try to keep in mind how the "reader" is going to read and assume stuff from what you've written. You probably don't want to insert doubt by having him read "In general, I . . ." Of course there are constraints, but don't put up red flags or even yellow ones.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nice idea. Tnx.

Comment: @F.E. Valid points… thanks for that heads-up. Hmmm, maybe worth an answer? I mean, I like upvoting comments – but they are hard to *accept*. ;)

Comment: It's a CV not a contract. Just use "Willing to relocate".

Answer (score 2):

The word is superfluous. If you are willing to move then you are generally willing to move. I discourage language that communicates nothing.

Comment: "Generally" is not superfluous in "I am generally willing to move."   It implies that there are exceptions of circumstance.  "I am willing to move," means I do not care to where.  Compare, "I am not generally willing to move, but I would move to Los Angeles." and "I am generally willing to move, but I would not move to the South."